# Missing lines from external table through pypyodbc

Tags: sql, python-3.x, netezza

Currently having issues with running sql code through pypyodbc in python. The odbc is connected to netezza to run sql code through there.

```
db = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = '''
   Create external table TABLE1 (
      col1,
      col2,
      col3
    )
   using (
      dataobject('C:\\file.txt')
      delimiter '|'
      quotedvalue 'DOUBLE'
      requiresquotes TRUE
      nullvalue ''
      escapechar '`'
      y2base 2000
      encoding 'internal'
      remotesource 'ODBC'
      logdir 'C:\\log'
    );

    Create table TABLE1_MAILBOX as (
       select * from TABLE1
      ) distribute on random;
   '''

cursor.execute(sql)
db.commit()
```

The first block of code that creates the external table works fine, it's when the second block of code that creates TABLE1_MAILBOX that things go wrong. It seems like it misses lines in TABLE1. For example, if the dataobject text file has 5000 lines, TABLE1 has 5000 lines, but TABLE1_MAILBOX has about 4750 lines.

**However**, if I run this code directly in netezza, it works just fine and each table has the correct amount of lines.

Not sure why it is doing through if it is run through pypyodbc in python. Could it be a glitch? Or am I doing something wrong?